# Why Matplotlib/seaborn alpha argument doesn't take lists or arrays?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

In matplotlib and seaborn, arguments such as size, color, style accepts lists/pandas columns.  *Is there any specific reason why alpha doesn't take list/array/column as argument*. While the problem can be addressed by sending pre-mapped colors, but simply able to do something like this would be much better

```
sns.scatterplot(x='SepalLengthCm',y='SepalWidthCm',data=df,alpha='Species')
```

Comment: *"Why?"* - because it hasn't been implemented as part of the API.

Comment: Yeah, but why only it was left. Colors, size accepts arrays and matplotlib is like a decade a old.

Comment: There are other arguments which do not take vectorized input either (e.g. marker). Specifically for alpha, it would clash with the alpha defined by the colors. So one would need to develop a clear concept of which one should take precendence. (Something like [4676](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4676) would need to be tackled first.) Matplotlib is developped by volunteers; if you are willing to contribute, please do so.